# time function in python not formatting to string

Tags: python, time

I have a python script that makes an API call to Symantec endpoint protection cloud every 15 minutes to download logs and then feed that back over into splunk. Part of the script includes a response post that requires 4 fields be set as follows:

```
{
    "feature_name": "ALL",
    "start_date": "2019-06-12T00:00:00.000+05:30",
    "end_date": "2019-07-12T00:00:00.000+05:30",
    "product": "SAEP"
}
```

The start_date and end_dates are what I am modifying in my script to include a start_date of the current time minus 15 min ago and the end_date of the current time. I have this beautifully formatted using the time function as follows.

```
import datetime
import time

ts = time.time() # current time in seconds from unix birth
ts_15 = ts - 900 # same as above but 15 min before

st = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3] + "-06:00" # format used for data to post to sep15
st_15 = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts_15).strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3] + "-06:00"  # same as st but 15 min ago; used as start time
```

Basically my data string in python starts out like this. Note the start and end dates are just a dummy number, they need to be swapped to a start_date of the current time - 15 min and then the end_date to the current time:

```
data = '{\n"feature_name": "ALL",\n"start_date": "2020-06-07T08:34:00.000-06:00",\n"end_date": "2020-06-08T13:35:00.000-06:00",\n"product": "SAEP",\n"limit":1000\n}'
```

What I do to modify the start and end dates is using the 
replace function on data as so:

```
for r in (("2020-06-07T08:34:00.000-06:00", st_15), ("2020-06-08T13:35:00.000-06:00", st)):
```

It changes those dates and I print them out and all looks IDENTICAL to the below which is just a static date, yet it complains.

```
for r in (("2020-06-07T08:34:00.000-06:00", "2020-06-12T18:00:00.000-07:00"), ("2020-06-08T13:35:00.000-06:00", "2020-06-12T18:08:00.000-07:00")):
    data = data.replace(*r)
```

I have even resorted to using awk and sed outside of this script executing those commands right before this script would run but I am still failing because while I got awk to literally replace my string with the current date and time, I cant get awk to process replacing the string with both start and end dates and saving this script like I would with sed using the -i flag, but the issue is with sed i can't seem to do that either, I tried multiple sed -e flags looking to alter only the line that begins with data. I tried all kinds of weird stuff with no luck.

There also seems to be an issue with the clock. I know there are some -06:00 here and then some mods I made using -07:00. It works with either one but if I try setting st or st_15 to anything but -06:00, it complains! i find that very strange!

And on the actual production server where this script runs, it has an actual UTC time running on it but I HAVE to use +01:00 or it will not work! Its as if the server is located an hour before or after UTC but still I am not understanding why my string which is being formatted with the time function and identical to what I need in my data set is not working. Its just a string and doesnt make sense.

If anyone could help, I would really appreciate it. Been killing myself with this for the last few days.

Thanks

Comment: By the way I can verify that on my local machine in PST, I can use the curl command with -07:00 and on the actual prod server, I can use -00:00 and that works perfectly. There is something with the time function that seems buggy to me, and something about the way python interprets certain strings

Comment: What do you mean by "it complains"? What is doing the "complaining", and how does that manifest? That is - how exactly do you try to use the code, what exactly happens when you try, and how exactly is that different from what is supposed to happen?

Comment: It complains by telling me that the piece following my response which I save, does not exist, and it wouldn't because this data never gets posted to the API. What should normally return is a huge dictionary and one of those fields is the events field. And so I save that into another variable and continue processing.

Comment: Please copy and paste any relevant error messages, and explain the exact steps that someone else would need to follow in order to reproduce them.

Comment: the start_date and end_date need to be dynamically changed yes. do I use `timedelta` here with the `data.replace()` ? please clarify. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all sorry, originally wanted to add only one comment, but the code sent is not formatted, so only add a answer.

I think you want to call api to get data every 15 minutes, so you need to make dynamic changes to start_date and end_date?

```
import time
import json
import requests
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
SF = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%M.%f"  # Since I don’t know your time zone, you need to change it yourself
while 1:
    start_date = datetime.now().strftime(SF) + "-06:00"
    end_date = (start_date-timedelta(minutes=15)).strftime(SF) + "-06:00"

    data = '{\n"feature_name": "ALL",\n"start_date": "2020-06-07T08:34:00.000-06:00",\n"end_date": "2020-06-08T13:35:00.000-06:00",\n"product": "SAEP",\n"limit":1000\n}'

    json_data = josn.loads(data)
    json_data["start_date"] = start_date
    json_data["end_date"] = end_date

    response = requests.post('https://api.sep.securitycloud.symantec.com/v1/event-search', headers=headers, data=json.dumps(json_data))
    # TODO: response to print or save ...
    # every 15 minutes
    time.sleep(15*60)
```

Comment: Yes forgot to add the actual call is this:

`response = requests.post('https://api.sep.securitycloud.symantec.com/v1/event-search', headers=headers, data=data)` so I need data to be modified here.

Comment: The format has to be `"2020-06-07T08:34:00.000-06:00"` or it will not work. I have both a script in PST and UTC so either would work. This is what I need help with.